# What software to use to know what projects to work on Weekly?

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a software that let me put the title of projects for each week for months ahead. Each week can have many titles for projects. I don't want these titles to overlap, so each title in one cell would be great. I tried to use MS Excel, but I'm sure there could be a better way to do it. I attach what I did for each week in Excel.[image]

Comment: Do you move them later on?  Are you looking for a task management system?